# AirPcap is end-of-availability. What alternatives do you recommend?

Tags: network, wifi, wireshark

I've been using Riverbed AirPcap dongles for Wi-Fi analysis for quite some time. But when I am trying to order more, I noticed all their AirPcap devices are end of life by Dec 31, 2017, for reason I don't know:
[End-of-Availability (EOA) Notice](https://support.riverbed.com/content/support/eos_eoa/steelcentral-cascade-opnet/AirPcap-NX_Classic-TX.html) from Riverbed web site.

Anyone has more info about this and what alternatives could we use instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no idea why Riverbed stopped selling these devices, here is my guess.

The [AirPcap FAQ](https://www.riverbed.com/document/fpo/AirPcap-Frequently-Asked-Questions.pdf) advertises the product as:

> AirPcap is  a family of  wireless capture devices and drivers representing the first open, affordable and easy to deploy 802.11 packet capture solutions for the Windows platform.

The page lists support for Windows 2000 up to Windows 7. The main differentiating feature is that it provided raw 802.11 capture support on Windows since this has to be provided by the driver. Over time, the driver APIs have changed a bit. It [reportedly](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/55396/has-anyone-had-success-using-a-riverbed-airpcap-with-windows-10) still works for Windows 10, but I *guess* that the Windows driver has not really been developed that much.

In meantime, 802.11ac is becoming more common while the AirPcap product line is still limited to 802.11n. So at the hardware level, it is also behind.

Now what probably killed it is the availability of the [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/) driver which also seems to provide raw 802.11 support for devices other than AirPcap (including [802.11ac](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/53412/support-for-80211ac-wireless-adapter)).

Concluding remark: if you were not limited to Windows, note that Linux has for a very long time supported raw 802.11 capture support for all devices that use the [mac80211 framework](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/mac80211) (where the Linux kernel is responsible for frame management). For educational purposes I just bought a €15 USB 802.11n adapter which I used on Linux. For me there was no reason to even consider an expensive AirPcap adapter (which has Windows support as its unique selling point).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, especially mentioning Npcap driver that supports Windows raw packet capturing. Windows support is still important to our team as most of them do not have access to Linux, but do have a need to analyze traffic. I see Npcap's raw frame capturing is still not as good as AirPcap. This link, https://secwiki.org/w/Npcap/WiFi_adapters, as of today(3/23/18)shows none of the supported adapters returns channel/frequency correctly. But I guess most people have moved to Linux for these applications. And the remaining Windows market is too small for Riverbed to care about. Sad.